# How to display the data retrieved from json

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to display the data retrieved from json array into my gridview using ArrayAdapter however whenever I try the below code it comes up with an error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference, so please advise what am I doing wrong

EmojiAdapter.java

```
public class EmojiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EmojiModel> {

private Context mContext;
Typeface typeface;
ArrayList<EmojiModel> list;

public EmojiAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = 
(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smiles_items_layout, null);

    ImageView imageView = 
(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.smile_image_view);

 imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position)
.getEmojiFile()));

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

StreamActivity.java

```
   Communicator.getInstance().on("subscribe start", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            try{

            JSONDictionary response = (JSONDictionary) args[0];
            String str = response.get("emojiPack").toString();
                JSONArray emojies = new JSONArray(str);

            for(int i=0;i<emojies.length();i++)
            {
                    JSONObject response2 = (JSONObject) 
            emojies.getJSONObject(i);
                    EmojiModel toAdd = new EmojiModel((String) 
            response2.get("urlFile"));
                    JSONDictionary t = 
            JSONDictionary.fromString(response2.toString());
                    toAdd.init(t);
           //The error appears from the below code
               emojiAdapter.add(toAdd);

} catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: Where in the code are you getting the Null Pointer Exception (NPE)? Also, just for more information, that means that the object you're attempting to work with isn't initialized or is set to null. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: The exception says that the null pointer exception is happening on the line you pointed out, which indicates the fact that the `emojiAdapter` itself is not initialized (or its value is `null`). Try to initialize the `emojiAdapter` variable with a non-null value before calling the `add` method on it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotten to initialize `ArrayList<EmojiModel> list`. Add the initialization in your constructor:

```
public EmojiAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    list = new ArrayList<EmojiModel>();
}
```

Also when your  emojiAdapter.add(toAdd); gets invoked the *variable* `emojiAdapter` is null.

Try backtracing where this variable got initialized and initialize it, there might be a problem when you pass the variable from your Activity/Fragment.

Comment: I've added it to the constructor however it's coming up with the same error

Comment: Can you tell me the line where the exception is thrown?

Comment: emojiAdapter.add(toAdd);

Comment: Your problem is that your adapter variable emojiAdapter isn't initialized, try to backtrace it until its initialization. Where do you initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<EmojiModel> list;

public EmojiAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,ArrayList<EmojiModel> list) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.list=list;
this.mContext=context;
}
```

You are getting Null pointer exception because in adapter your list is not initialized. You have send list from your activity to adapter via constructor and set initialize like this `this.list=list;` and any other variables like your context is not initialize too use `this.mContext=context`